# Connecting Oracle SQL developer to GitHub Actions

Tags: oracle, github-actions, devops

I just started a job as a junior DevOps and I'm working with GitHub Actions and I want to be able to connect to the Oracle SQL developer to GitHub Actions. The reason is because I have a GitHub Actions workflow that builds packages and I take the SHA number of the latest commit that was the last build. I keep a table of the SHA numbers of each build.

P.s. If there is another way to do this within GitHub I would also appreciate that.

I tried to connect with IP/domain, username, password and there is something missing

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is a client application that is used to connect to databases; it is **NOT** a database.